# Laravel Forbidden You don't have permission to access /storage/ on this server

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, centos

recently, i deploy my laravel project to Centos 7 VPS
and i have images that saved in storage file

when i'm trying to access the images using URL i got this

```
    Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /storage/companies/1597187294.jpg on this server.
```

i think it something related to permissions cause everything works fine in localhost

So, any ideas to fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to run below command

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /storage
```

or

run these blow commands step by step

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache

chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
chmod -R 775 public
```